# How to call a java method (other than servlet) to jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a register user page, where i have the option to enter username and password. On clicking on the register button, i need to validate whether the user is already in database.

If the user exists i need to display a hidden label and stay on the screen, or else navigate to the next page.

**JSP Code**

```
<%@ page import="pkg.Login.*"%> 
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<Script type = "text/javascript">
    function ManFieldValidation()
    {
        String tempVal = document.forms["form1"]["txtUserID"].value;
        UserExistingCheck strObj = new UserExistingCheck();
        boolean iReturn = strObj.CheckIDExist(tempVal);
        return iReturn
    }
</Script>
<body>
    <form name = "form1" onSubmit = "return ManFieldValidation()" action = "ServRegister" method="post">
        <label id = "lblUserError" style="visibility:hidden;"><font color = "red">The User ID is already available</font></label><br></br>
        <label>User ID</label>
        <input type = "text"name = "txtUserID" size="8" maxlength="10"></input>

        <label>Password</label>
        <input type = "password" name = "txtPassword" size="8" maxlength="10"></input>

        <input type = "submit" class = "tfbutton" name = "Register" value = "Register"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JSP - "Register.jsp"

Servlet - "ServRegister.java" (to insert the data to database if user doesn't exist)

Since i already have a servlet; i tried writing a java method to validate about the existing user and return the either true or false. Below is the java code.

**Java Method**

```
package pkg.Login;
import java.sql.*;
public class UserExistingCheck 
{
    public void CheckIDExist(String tempVal)
    {
        try
        {
            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"+
                    "databaseName=WebPortal;user=VRHAJAS;Password=Vignesh007";                    
            Connection conn = null;
            Statement select = null;
            ResultSet result = null;

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            select = conn.createStatement();
            String sQuery = "Select * from dbo.UserDetails where UserID = '" + tempVal + "'";
            result=select.executeQuery(sQuery);
            conn.close();               
            if(result.next())
            {   
            return false;           
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }   

        catch (Exception e)
        {                           
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }       
    }
}
```

When i click the register button, the above method is not called upon. Instead "ServRegister.java" is executed. There is no error also getting displayed. I'm using eclipse. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a REST architecture. Annotations will build the path to the method to be invoked, you will only have to execute an AJAX on client side.

Comment: Thanks Burcea. Without using any complex architectures, is there any simple way of doing what i did above ?

Comment: This thing was first in my mind, it is not complex and if I would have a similar task, I will definitely not look for other solutions. Also, please use PreparedStatement and avoid catch(Exception ex), try to catch specific exceptions.